# How do i re-download the Scripts file in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I am training on ASP.NET Webforms, and I deleted one of the files that came with the program when creating it. I want to re-download the file because deleting it caused chaos in the web page, and I don't know how to re-download the file and where to get the file

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cj9bG.png)

Answer (score 1):

Steps to recover `scripts` files

1. Open `Nuget Package Manager`
2. Type `jQuery` and install it
3. Type `bootstrap` and install it
4. Type `jquery.validate` and install it

`If those packages are already installed, uninstall them and reistall it again.`

Note: `It will get all the scripts that comes when you create project.`